# Read a large result set in chunks from mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to read a huge result set from mysql. Reading them in a straight-forward manner didn't work, as mysql tries to return all results together, which times out.

I found the [following piece of code](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html) which tells mysql to read the results back one at a time:

```
stmt = conn.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

Can I read a chunk at a time instead of one by one? I've tried setting fetch size to a different value, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query use pagination by setting limit and offset.